# Select hyphenated work with double-click in Sublime Text for Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

On my older Mac, I have somehow set it up so that if I double-click on a hyphenated word, I select the whole thing (all the part and the hyphens).

I just got a new Mac and am setting it up, but somehow double-clicking a hyphenated word only select the word I only get the part I clicked on.  The word is separated by the hyphen.

I checked the setting in my Sublime Text 3 prefs for word separators, and the hyphen is NOT there:

```
"word_separators": "./\\()\"',.;:<>~!%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"
```

So, where is this set?  In sublime or somewhere in the OS?

Comment: My default preferences file in ST3 has this line `"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"` So copying this with the hyphen removed to user preference has done the trick